# File names stacking during for loop

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I am new to shell script, so this might be a dumb question.  I haven't found an answer online though.  I am taking a coworkers script and changing it so that it works for my data.  Right now I am running a test that only uses three of my data files.  The code hits a spot in the script where it goes through a for loop and it is supposed to run through the loop once for each of the different files (three times).

```
listtumor=`cat /Users/TReiersen/Work-Folder/OV/DataProcessing/TestRun/MatchedTumorTest.txt`
for i in $listtumor
do
lst=`ls /Users/TReiersen/Work-Folder/OV/DataProcessing/TestRun/freshstart/${i}*.txt | awk -F'/' '{print $9}'`
```

MatchedTumorTest.txt just contains the three different file names that I am using for the test without '.txt'  As far as I can tell, this code should just run through the script three times, one for each file.  Instead I am getting this error:

```
ls: /Users/TReiersen/Work-Folder/OV/DataProcessing/TestRun/freshstart/TCGA-04-1514-01A-01D-0500-02_S01_CGH_105_Dec08\rTCGA-04-1530-01A-02D-0500-02_S01_CGH_105_Dec08\rTCGA-04-1542-01A-01D-0500-02_S01_CGH_105_Dec08*.txt: No such file or directory
```

For some reason all of the file names are stacked on top of each other instead of the loop going to each one individually.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks,
T.J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the lines in your text file may be separated by carriage returns instead of newlines. Since none of the file names in your example have spaces, the `for` loop should work just fine if you initialize your `listtumor` like this:

```
listtumor=`tr '\r' '\n' < /Users/TReiersen/Work-Folder/OV/DataProcessing/TestRun/MatchedTumorTest.txt`
```

The `tr` command will translate the carriage returns into newlines, which is what most text-processors (like the shell's own for command) will expect), and write the result to standard output.

Comment: This worked as well!  I was asked not to use the while loop, so I used this instead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The for loop doesn't do too well with some kinds of separators. Try this instead:

```
while read line; do
    lst=`ls /Users/TReiersen/Work-Folder/OV/DataProcessing/TestRun/freshstart/${line}*.txt | awk -F'/' '{print $9}'`
    ...
done < /Users/TReiersen/Work-Folder/OV/DataProcessing/TestRun/MatchedTumorTest.txt
```

I'm assuming here that you're separating MatchedTumorTest.txt with newlines.

Comment: @Chris It appears to have gotten rid of the original error, but now I am getting different error.

Comment: qc-column-level-tumorTEST.sh: line 104: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: I don't know if this is related to the change that was made or not; I will monkey around with it for a while.

Comment: @T.J., use `<` not `<<` for file redirection on the `done` line

Answer (score 1):

So combined all together:

```
dir="/Users/TReiersen/Work-Folder/OV/DataProcessing/TestRun"
file="$dir/MatchedTumorTest.txt"

< "$file" tr '\r' '\n' | while read tumor
do
   ls "$dir/freshstart" | grep "$tumor.*\.txt$" 
done
```

will print all .txt file-names in the directory $dir/freshstart what contain a name form the file MatchedTumorTest.txt